# Why doesn't this WordPress $wpdb query work?

Tags: wordpress

I am doing the following:

```
$type = 'attachment';
$images = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare('

                SELECT p.*
                FROM wp_%d_posts p
                WHERE p.post_parent =%d
                AND p.post_type = "%s"


    ', $blog_id, $page->ID, $type),OBJECT);


var_dump($images);
```

If I remove the line 'AND p.post_type = "%s"' then I get results returned, otherwise I get an empty array returned. If I run the query direct against the DB in a mysql client, I get results.

There is no error, just an empty result set. I am doing similar queries throughout my file and they are working so I'm not looking for "don't do it like that" style replies. I just need to understand why this isn't working and fix it.

PHP 5.3, MYSQL 5.1. WordPress MU 2.9.2

Comment: Are you sure there ARE attachments that are children of `$page->ID`?

Comment: yes. If I run the query directly against the DB, I get results. As stated, I also get results if I remove the AND part of the where clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not Quote `"%s"`.  From the WordPress site, "Notice that you do not have to worry about quoting strings. Instead of passing the variables directly into the SQL query, use a `%s` placeholder for strings and a `%d` placedolder for integers."

**Example:**

`$wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( "UPDATE $wpdb->posts SET post_title = %s WHERE ID = %d", $var, $id ) );`

Comment: Thanks but I tried that and it doesn;t make any difference. I also tried loads of different combinations of quotes, single quotes, escaped quotes. No difference.

Comment: Your code as posted is wrong according to the Wordpress manual.  I pointed that out, and you mark the answer as wrong?  It certainly appears as if you are not handling the Prepare statement properly...

Comment: sorry - if you edit the answer I will vote it back up. Just a bit stressed :-(